# Issue when creating a Data Extension within shared folder using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs, automationstudio

I could create a Data Extension successfully within any folder inside Data Extension parent folder using the below code. But when I do it for Shared Data Extension, I am not successful, could anyone please let me know how to do I create the Data Extension within Shared Items/ Shared Data Extensions folder?

```
<script runat="server">

  
 Platform.Load("core","1");

 
  /*  fetch folder */
var FolderAttributes = Folder.Retrieve({ Property: "Name", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value:"Testing"});
    
  var FolderID = FolderAttributes[0].ID; 
  
 try{
 
 var obj1={ 
  "Name" :"1Test_create_DE",
  "CustomerKey" : "1Test_create_DE1",
   "CategoryID": FolderID,
  "Fields": [
   { "Name" : "Field1", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 },
   { "Name" : "Field2", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 },
   { "Name" : "Field ", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 }
    
  ] 
  };
  
/*  function*/ 
var myDe=DataExtension.Add(obj1);
 }
  
  catch(err)
  {
  Write ("cannot create DE: "+err);
  }
   
</script>
```

Comment: are you executing this code in a child BU and trying to create the DE in the shared folder?

Comment: yes correct, I am running this in one of our child BUs

Comment: I bet if you ran this in the parent account it would create it succesfully. I also imagine that its created just not visible,